# How to prevent from storing empty user settings file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I would like to use C# Application settings. I use only `Application` scope, but even though "empty" user settings file is created in my `user\AppData\Local\myApp\...` and in `user\AppData\Roaming\myApp\...`.

Content of those files `user.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to prevent creation of those files?